# 4 buttons toggle 4 different divs, wrapper height transition with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a newbie in jQuery and Javascript in general, and what I'm trying to achieve is that 4 buttons show 4 different divs.

The idea is that the 4 divs can be seen together at the same time if you click on the 4 buttons, and if you click them again they close BUT the wrapper does not shrink and stays the size of when the divs are opened.

I know that you can not make a transition to the height of a div. Then I am trying to remove a class from the wrapper if the user "close" all the divs.

This is what i'm trying:

```
if($('.show-divs').length == 3) {
    $('#divs-wrapper').removeClass('expand');
}
```

But ofcourse is not working, is there way to acomplish what i want?, thanks.

This is a representation of the divs closed
[image]

This is a representation of the divs after click all the buttons
[image]

Comment: you should provide some code to work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a different ID attribute to each div you want to show and then add the following attribute to each button.

```
data-target="#THEID"
```

then use the following jquery:

```
$('.show-divs').click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $(target).toggleClass('expand');
});
```

Assuming show-divs is your button class, warning, I typed this on my phone.

If you want to animate the heights you could do something like this:

```
    $(".show-divs").toggle(function(){
        var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
        $(target).animate({maxHeight:1000},200);
    },function(){
        var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
        $(target).animate({maxHeight:0},200);
    });
```

As height would be auto but max-height would animate the height of the div between 0 and its max height (assuming it's less than 1000, you can change that to suit)

Here's a fiddle :) 
http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/3328/

Comment: I just took a look at your fiddle, that's exactly what i need! i'm going to try it on my code and tell you how is working, thanks!

Comment: Awesome :) Hope it works for you! I'm rather proud it worked as I typed it on my phone!

Comment: I have been trying many ways to make your code work but, I have some animations for the buttons when you scroll to that point of the website, which does not allow me to make your code work.

I leave you a codepen to be if you can help me. [link](http://codepen.io/AbasuDESIGN/pen/WoPJge)

Comment: I did it! is working now! thanks for the help. this was the solution:

Comment: `var showDiv1 = document.getElementById('show-div1');
showDiv1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var text1 = document.getElementById('text1');
    text1.classList.toggle('expand');
});`

Comment: I just made it work with your codepen, sorry I dont know Pug so did not enjoy that haha. Here it is: I couldnt use toggle so made a class toggle change and added the max-height change there.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVZqEG

Comment: But you also got it working! haha so well done :) Thanks for the recognition! Also, your html didnt have the data-target attributes that the code was trying, the codepen in my previous comment utilises that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, step by step i'm improving my Js/jQuery skills.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure I completely comprehend what you are tring to accomplish. But if it is to just make a div appear and disappear you can add a css style of

```
display: none;
```

this makes it seem as if the div doesn't exist (so it doesn't take up space) then using javascript on the button such as

```
onclick="this.style.display = 'whatever display value'";
```

or replace 'display' with 'visibility' 
this allows the div to not show yet still take up the space it would if it was showing so from

```
visibility: hidden -> visibility: visible
```

Comment: ah sorry I was a bit distracted, you are correct! I meant visible for 'visibility'.

Comment: And the onclick function, wow such a stupid mistake maybe I should just not answer anything today and go to sleep.